# How to tunnel all network traffic (both directions) on one public IP address to a different machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, forward, tunnel

I've got an IP with decades of positive email reputation which is whitelisted and inserted into hundreds of client firewalls.  It is 69.1.1.1  (not really, just assume; but 1st octet is correct).

My ISP got sold, and lost all it's IPs.  My physical centos megaserver has now been given an all new IPs, including: 162.2.2.2 (again, just assume; but 1st octet is correct). Lets call this "BOX-P", since it's physical.

The new owners of the IPs have allowed me to run a small CentOS VM in their system to which they will point all my 69.1.1.1 traffic.  Lets call this "BOX-V", since it's virtual.

I need somehow to adjust BOX-P so that it can still send and receive traffic over 69.1.1.1

I'm guessing this means I need to "tunnel" from BOX-V to BOX-P and also back again somehow.

Would anyone here know what I should be doing, both in "high level" suggestions (eg: yes - you need a tunnel), and also "low level" ones (eg: run this ... on BOX-P and run this ... on BOX-V) ?

I've found a bunch of tunneling examples, but they're all using private subnets and NAT, so I'm totally lost about how on earth to "tunnel" a *public* IP over to a second *public* IP, with no private anything involved!

Note that I do understand how to set up BOX-V to receive and originate TCP traffic over the "non-primary" ethernet (or other) port (eg: binding to an alternate interface)... it's just how to set such an interface up that I'm lost with.

No encryption is needed, and I do not need broadcast traffic either - mostly just ports 22/25/53/466/587/443/80 [including UDP and ICMP if possible] and an assortment of other custom ports for other services I run here.

Thanks a gazillion in advance for any help you can lend!!

Comment: My own "baby steps"; I'm thinking I do not need a tunnel?  The following does seem to send incoming packets to the other server:-
    `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 69.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 162.2.2.2`
but I now need to get my head around how to connect up the opposite direction, so returning packets go back again.
---

Comment: p.s. anyone know how to **print** out the above command?  After I issue it, `iptables -L` does not show anything different...

Comment: Above stopped working with `ICMP host 69.1.1.1 unreachable - admin prohibited` errors - which kindof makes sense.  My 69.* server should not really be allowed to "spoof" the senders IP address anytime it wants to send out packets...  back to drawing board. Looks like a tunnel *is* needed.

Comment: false alarm; rebooted and forgot the echo `1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: In frustration, I hacked the BOX-P with a custome netfilter I wrote to forcefully change the IP from 162.2.2.2 to 69.1.1.1 ... I can see in tcpdump that this is working (packets correctly "turn up" in response to ping/SYN/etc), but, they're not being *understood* when they come back now :-( kernel just seems to be totally ignoring them. What causes good packets to get ignored? do I have to do checksums as well?

Comment: Damn; seems I got it working, except one of my 2 ISPs is dropping "spoofed" packets. So yeah. Looks like I do need some kind of tunnel now... but I totally cannot get my head around that stuff!!! Anyone know how to use "`modprobe ipip`" or "`modprobe tun`" for this kind of thing?